# How to differentiate same class HTML present in two different div

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordian/jquery-1.9.1.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
  var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();
   $("#ordersdiv").prepend(divdata);
$("#ordersdiv .Topping-details").hide();
  });


 </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div  class="activateUiHTML"  data-role="collapsible">
   <div class="prd-items-detials">
      <form><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclas" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="59" > 
         <label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Ice Cream Butter Scotch</label> 
      </form>
      <div class="Topping-details" id="59">
         <section id="topping_tsection_59">
            <i id="topping-close"></i>
            <aside>
               <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
            </aside>
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div id="ordersdiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

When clicked on the CheckBox , i have a listener in which i am appending data to the div called **ordersdiv**
and hide the elements with class "**Topping-details**" only if they are child elements of the "**ordersdiv**" element.

Now i am struck at this place .

I have got listener for .Topping-details  as shown below which works in common for both the orders div and activateUiHTML div

```
$(document).on("click", ".Topping-details", function () 
{

    alert('ddd');

});
```

How can i diferentiate click event  for .Topping-details present  under **ordersdiv** and .Topping-details under **activateUiHTML** div

http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/2/

Comment: You can use `.closest()` to find parent then check its length like http://jsfiddle.net/CLU5y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#ordersdiv .Topping-details", function(){
    alert('ddd');
});
```

and

```
$(document).on("click", ".activateUiHTML .Topping-details", function(){
    alert('aaa');
});
```

P.S. ids shouldn't start with numbers!

Comment: 1. You are missing `#` with `ordersdiv` and `.activateUiHTML` 2. IDs in HTML5 can start with number

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of closest orderdiv:

```
 if($(this).closest('#ordersdiv').length){
   //in order div
 }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhdJ3/)**

Comment: Thank you very much , i was thinking whole night as how to resolve this , you experts solved this within minutes . Thank you once again .

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/5/)**

Check this,

```
$(document).on("click", ".Topping-details", function () 
{
    if($(this).parents('#ordersdiv').length){
        alert('ordersdiv')
    }
    else{
        alert('activateUiHTML')
    }
});
```

You have to check if the currently clicked `.Toppping-details` has a parent name `ordersdiv`.

Use `$(this).parents('#ordersdiv').length` for this. `length` will return 0 if it does not exist.

Reference :

- **[.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)** : Get specifed ancestors.
- **[.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)** : Get no. of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find parent then check its length

*Code*

```
$(document).on("click", ".Topping-details", function () {
    var ordersdiv = $(this).closest('#ordersdiv').length;
    var activateUiHTML = $(this).closest('div.activateUiHTML').length;

    if (ordersdiv) {
        alert('Under ordersdiv');
    }
    if (activateUiHTML) {
        alert('Under activateUiHTML');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8nFgB/)